# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError , Missing bin folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I compile the Android app using Android studio I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

And when I checked the app folder there is no bin folder there but classpath is set to `project/bin`

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: What Class is not found? The `bin/` folder is not a common place to put Android files in an apk

Comment: @JBirdVegas the first class that is going to be used inside my app

Comment: Is your class in the `bin` folder? Or is it a `jar` or `aar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

Note: You can specify the multiDexEnabled setting in the defaultConfig, buildType, or productFlavor sections of your Gradle build file.

Run a Gradle sync.
In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element.

https://coderwall.com/p/fprsjg/fixing-over-65k-methods-limitation-build-error-for-android-on-android-studio